# Show that $\mathfrak{gl}_3(\mathbb{C}) = \mathfrak{sl}_3(\mathbb{C}) \oplus \mathfrak{s}_3(\mathbb{C})$

Tags: lie-algebras

> **Question:** Show that $\mathfrak{sl}_3(\mathbb{C})$ and $\mathfrak{s}_3(\mathbb{C})$ are ideals in $\mathfrak{gl}_3(\mathbb{C})$ and $\mathfrak{gl}_3(\mathbb{C}) = \mathfrak{sl}_3(\mathbb{C}) \oplus \mathfrak{s}_3(\mathbb{C})$.

**My attempt:** For all $A \in \mathfrak{gl}_3(\mathbb{C})$. If $\text{tr}(A) = 0$ then $A \in \mathfrak{sl}_3(\mathbb{C})$; else $A = \frac{\text{tr}(A)}{3} I + (A - \frac{\text{tr}(A)}{3} I)$ with $\text{tr}(A - \frac{\text{tr}(A)}{3} I) = 0$, i.e., $A - \frac{\text{tr}(A)}{3} I \in \mathfrak{sl}_3(\mathbb{C})$. Clearly $\mathfrak{sl}_3(\mathbb{C}) \cap \mathfrak{s}_3(\mathbb{C}) = \{0\}$. Hence $\mathfrak{gl}_3(\mathbb{C}) = \mathfrak{sl}_3(\mathbb{C}) \oplus \mathfrak{s}_3(\mathbb{C})$.

Is my proof true and how to prove that $\mathfrak{sl}_3(\mathbb{C})$ and $\mathfrak{s}_3(\mathbb{C})$ are ideals? Thank all!

Comment: What is $\mathfrak{s}_3(\mathbb{C})$?

Comment: Presumably $\mathfrak{s}_3(\Bbb{C})$ stands for the 1-dimensional space of 3x3 scalar matrices? To prove that they are ideals you need the rule $tr(AB)=tr(BA)$ for all square matrices $A,B$. If you have never seen that fact, prove it first!

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown $\mathfrak{s}_3(\mathbb{C})$ is a Lie subalgebra of all matrix has form $aI$ with $a \in \mathbb{C}$ and $I$ is the unit matrix.

Comment: Show $[A,B]$ has trace zero. Also show that $[A,B]=0$ when $A$ is a scalar matrix.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown all matrix in $\mathfrak{sl}_3(\mathbb{C})$ and $\mathfrak{s}_3(\mathbb{C})$ are $3 \times 3$ square matrix, so we have $tr(AB) = tr(BA)$ and $[A,B] = AB - BA$ has trace zero.

Comment: Your proof of the vector space decomposition is fine by the way. All the comments will lead you to show the summands are ideals.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg We know that all matrix in $\mathfrak{sl}_3(\mathbb{C})$ and $\mathfrak{s}_3(\mathbb{C})$ are $3 \times 3$ square matrix, so $tr(AB) = tr(BA)$ and applies it to the commutator $[A,B] = AB - BA$ then we get $tr([A,B]) = 0$. Is that enough to conclude that $\mathfrak{sl}_3(\mathbb{C})$ and $\mathfrak{s}_3(\mathbb{C})$ are ideals?

Comment: Would be great to use another notation, it's hard to distinguish $\mathfrak{sl}()$ and $\mathfrak{s}()$ (the latter is not very usual notation).